# How to add Filesystem functionality to my capacitor app working with android > 13

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I want to save a `.pdf` file in the file system of the users smartphone.

I followed this capacitor [documentation](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/filesystem) and did.

1. Add the following to my `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

2. Checking the permissions

```js
geFilesystemAccess(): Promise<boolean> {
  return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    const status = await Filesystem.checkPermissions()
    const state = status.publicStorage

    if (state === 'granted') {
      console.log('worked -> do save the file')
      return resolve(true)
    } else if (state === 'denied') {
      console.log('denied -> ask the user to change the access himself')
      if(await this._requestToEditSettings('ALLOW_FILESYSTEM_ACCESS'))
      NativeSettings.open({
        optionAndroid: AndroidSettings.ApplicationDetails,
        optionIOS: IOSSettings.App,
      })
    } else {
      Filesystem.requestPermissions()
    }
    return resolve(false)
  })
}
```

Even if the user never denied the access, the state will be `denied`.
Then, when the user to open his settings, he wont be able to enable access to the fileSystem.

This is actually working on Android 12

#### Additional

I saw I could use an [Intent](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files) but I do not understand how I should do this.

Did somebody faced the same problem & already did found the fix?

#### Edit

I did try to add a [granular media permissions](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions), but is sadly didn't fixed the problem

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
```

Comment: Not sure if this falls under your category, but could be of use: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions

Comment: Often times with XPlatform tools you need to go the actual native docs to see if there is any misalignment or missing information from the XPlatform documentation

Comment: @SomeStudent I tried to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />` to my `AndroidManifest.xml` file with no success.

I'm also wondering if pdf does play a roles, since this seems to be more for images & videos

Comment: Uncertain, I would suspect pdf would fall under image. Try cancelling out of the app or doing a clean install on your device/emulator to ensure no funky caching business is going on

Comment: A pdf file is no image so you cannot write it to a public  image directory like DCIM or Pictures. Try public  Documents and Download directory instead or a subdir of them.

Comment: @blackapps Thx for the clarification, I actually just want to check the access permission. I do save it here `Directory.Documents` but this is the checkPermissions that is failing

Comment: Why do you care? Better try to write. Test it!

Comment: @blackapps, I do care since this is the part that is not working & also since I've an error writing it (the permission is denied..)